# Non-testable base class extending PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, subclassing, base-class

### Summary

How can I create a base class that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and use that for subclassing actual test cases, without having the base class itself tested by PHPUnit?

### Further explanation

I have a series of related test cases for which I have created a base class that contains some common tests to be inherited by all test cases:

```
BaseClass_TestCase.php:
class BaseClass_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { 
  function test_common() {
    // Test that should be run for all derived test cases
  }
}

MyTestCase1Test.php:
include 'BaseClass_TestCase.php';
class MyTestCase1 extends BaseClass_TestCase {
    function setUp() {
      // Setting up
    }
    function test_this() {
      // Test particular to MyTestCase1
    }
}

MyTestCase2Test.php:
include 'BaseClass_TestCase.php';
class MyTestCase2 extends BaseClass_TestCase {
    function setUp() {
      // Setting up
    }
    function test_this() {
      // Test particular to MyTestCase2
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to run all the tests in the folder, it fails (without output).

Trying to debug I've found that the problem lies with the base class being itself a subclass of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and therefore PHPUnit will also try to run its tests. (Until then I naively thought that only classes defined inside actual test files - filenames ending in Test.php - would be tested.)

Running the base class as a test case out of context doesn't work due to details in my specific implementation.

How can I avoid the base class being tested, and only test the derived classes?

Comment: For everyone that got here with similar problem - check this post because it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20074589/4483415

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make it abstract, PHPUnit should ignore it.

Comment: My problem with this is that I use the Yii framework, and the Yii class autoloader does not seem to recognize abstract classes. I get the error `Class 'unit/MasterDataValidatorTest' could not be found in '<project>/protected/tests/unit/MasterDataValidatorTest.php'.`. Do you know a solution to that as well? :-)

Comment: Couldn't you use final instead?

Comment: @Maximum86 Have you tried it? I haven't. A final class is still able to be instantiated so my guess would be PHPUnit would consider it a test class.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding any file being tested, you can exclude it in `phpunit.xml` file. In your case is `<exclude>./tests/BaseClass_TestCase.php</exclude>`
[Whole file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQ57.png)